# Поиск наличия элементов списка в столбце Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть список:

```
words=['добр', 'здрав']
```

и столбец Dataframe

```
df['Text1']:
0    добрый день
1    решил
2    доброго времени
3    выполняет
4    здравствуйте
```

Сейчас я проверяю наличие хотя бы одного из элементов из списка words в сроках df['Text'] и создаю новый столбец df['Text2'] так:

```
df['Text2']=df['Text1'].str.contains('добр|здрав')


df['Text2']:
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
```

Как можно напрямую проверять наличие элементов из списка words в сроках df['Text1']? Т.е. чтобы вбивать нужные слова в список words, а не в str.contains().

Также интересуют возможности решения с помощью других методов кроме str.contains().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'|'.join(words)` - динамически сгенерирует нужный вам RegExp:

```
In [475]: '|'.join(words)
Out[475]: 'добр|здрав'
```

Пример:

```
In [474]: df.Text1.str.contains('|'.join(words))
Out[474]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Text1, dtype: bool
```